# How to save the facebook comment in database after posting it to facebook in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-comments

I want to save the facebook comment in my database of rails application after user posts it on facebook from my application.

Say there is facebook comment box added to my site. 
Now when user enters facebook post and clicks on "comment" or "post" button provided by facebook. The comment is currently posted on facebook but i want it to post in facebook as well as  save it to my application's database.

Thanks in advance for any help,